# Replacing a Li-Ion battery with a capacitor and power supply in a bluetooth speaker

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, bluetooth, speakers, replacement

I have a Philips BT3500 speaker with a dead Lithium Ion battery.

I want to be able to use the speaker without the battery - using just the power supply. It used to work for some time with the usb charger plugged in, but recently the speaker has trouble starting even with the charger connected.
I suspected that the old battery was pulling all the power and thus the speaker didn't have enough to work with. I thus removed the battery completely, and now the speaker works when the charger is connected - which was my goal.

The only problem now is that it shuts down/restarts, when the music is too loud - and I assume that is because there is no battery that can provide a power buffer for sudden spikes in demand.
Hence I am wondering if it would be feasible to use a capacitor for this purpose? How would I go about this?

The Li-Ion battery was a 3.7V 2200mAh cell.

Comment: The larger the better. You might try a 5 V 1 F supercapacitor with low series resistance, or a large electrolytic. That said, you're fighting against the charge-limiting circuit that prevents damage to the LI-ion cell. If you can bypass the current limiter (not voltage limiter!), you might not need an aetra capacitor.

Comment: The impedance of a good Li-Ion is about 65 mOhm and 10kF . A dead battery will be >> 10x ESR and <<10% C So it must be better than this.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik thanks for the reply. I can see that they use a 4056E charging module but it looks like the input to it is 5v. Would it work, if i just bridged the input and the output pins? 5V and the 4.2V that a full battery provides shouldn't make much difference.. (I hope)

Comment: Large electrolytic across the 5V. 10,000uF would be a decent first guess. Select a track and volume that shuts it down, add cap, and play same track.

Comment: @tommyleejones, it might be OK... but check the unloaded output of the nominal 5 VDC supply... if it's *much* above 5 V, maybe not.